# How to get data from table using select query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I am not asking for the simple select query. I have a detailed table which have multiple records. I want to fetch record for particular id but in some manner.

I have tried below query:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `po_id` ,  `part_id` ,  `qty` ,  `price` ,  `status` ,  `lotid` 
FROM  `po_details` 
WHERE  `po_id` =3
```

and it gives me below result:

[image]

Now what I want is get all above data but order by id and then order by partid, so the result would be like this

```
id     partid
----   ------
11     27
15     27
12     43
16     43
13     102
14     15
17     24
```

can anyone help me? what changes required into my query to get my desire result?

**EDIT**

I have already tried this query but it gives me the same result

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `po_id` ,  `part_id` ,  `qty` ,  `price` ,  `status` ,  `lotid` 
FROM  `po_details` 
WHERE  `po_id` =3 
ORDER BY `id` ,  `part_id`;
```

Thanks,

Pkachhia

Comment: You say you want to order by ID and then by partID but your expected result suggests the other way around *(only 13 being out of place then)*. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Strike that last comment. Actually, I have **no** idea how your sort order should be determined *(given that those outputs are correct)*. Your first 6 results seem to be sorted on `partID`. The last two could be either one but **why** are id's 14&17 last in your result?

Comment: what i want is, select all part id for given id but in the manner of how user inserted it, and if any part id is repeated then they are come together. May be now it is more clear to you.

Comment: @pkacchia - in that case you'll need an additional column to sort on, be it the time of insertion, a home made incremental number or an identity column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lieven said your need an additional column for sorting. As workaround you can use :

```
select p1.*
from po_details p1 join
(
    select min(id) order_id,  po_id ,  part_id 
    from po_details
    where po_id =3 
    group by part_id, po_id
) p2 on p1.part_id = p2.part_id and p1.po_id = p2.po_id
order by p2.order_id,p1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  `id` ,  `po_id` ,  `part_id` ,  `qty` ,  `price` ,  `status` ,  `lotid` 
FROM  `po_details` 
WHERE  `po_id` =3 
ORDER BY `id` ,  `part_id`;
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it gives me the same result as I have posted in my question.see my updates